# Accessing variables from another class Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to android development and I'm wondering how this can be done. I have a class named ListDeadlines with variables such as

```
public ArrayList<String> arrayList;
public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
public EditText txtInput;
```

I want to be able to access these variables in a different class. I have tried it like this, however I get the fallowing error on my `lst.txtInput lst.arrayList lst.adapter` saying `Variable 'lst' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final.` Anyone got any ideas on how to access variables in another class.

```
    ListDeadlines lst= new ListDeadlines();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    lst.txtInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtinput);
    Button btAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newItem = lst.txtInput.getText().toString();
           lst.arrayList.add(newItem);
            lst.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Android Studio. Try making the class implement the interface and putting the code in there instead of using an inner class

Comment: Well I'm developing my application in Android Studio so it does have something to do with Android Studio.

Comment: I mean its not Android Studio that is causing the problem. The headline is misleading. Try public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener. Then in the OnClick method you should be able to use your global variable no problem

Comment: Try to add `final` modifier: `final ListDeadlines lst= new ListDeadlines();`

Comment: Just Declare your variable final.

Comment: I wonder if this is in the top 10 most frequently asked questions.  https://www.google.com/search?q=android+variable+from+another+class+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is access the variable lst from within an anonymous inner class in the same scope as lst.  The anonymous inner class is your `new View.OnClickListener`.  The rules for doing this in Java require that you declare lst as `final` so that the inner class can be certain that lst will not change when it eventually executes.  So, you can declare your lst like this:

```
final ListDeadlines lst= new ListDeadlines();
```

Or you can make lst a member of the enclosing class that contains the method where it's currently defined.